# I'm trying to understand how to remove arguments with partialy applying a function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

How come words2 and words are giving the same result? I know some currying but I can't understand this example below.

```js
function curry(fn) {
  const arity = fn.length;
  return function $curry(...args) {
    if (args.length < arity) {
      return $curry.bind(null, ...args);
    }
    return fn.call(null, ...args);
  };
}

const split = curry((sep, str) => str.split(sep));
const words = split(' ');
const words2 = str => split(' ', str)

console.log(words('something cool'))
console.log(words2('something cool'))
```

words equals to split(' ') function but what happens when I call words again with a string and how can it be equal to words2 function?

Comment: Can you please post the `curry` function? Have you written it or are you using something from a library?

Comment: It's from a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply `curry` to the `split` function it's like getting back two versions of the split function:

```js
function split(sep, str){
  str.split(sep);
}
```

and

```
function split(sep) {
  return function(str) {
   return str.split(sep);
  }
}
```

and which one is called is based on the number of parameters provided. So for the case of `words` you call the 2nd version with `' '` and then you call the returned function with `'something cool'` which means that the actual code running is:

```js
'something cool'.split(' ')
```

In the other case of `words2` you call the 1st version and the actual code running:

```js
'something cool'.split(' ')
```

That's why you get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Because `split(' ', str)` and `split(' ')(str)` gives the same result
And calling `words2` calls the former while calling `words` calls the latter